# How to url redirect orld wordpress blog to new wordpress blog

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I'm asking a wired question here. Actually there is a way to do this for blogger to wordpress migration as stated in labnol.org. But I'm asking that suppose I'm transefing my blog to a new domain and have exported the posts from old sie & imported to the new one. Now I'm looking for some trick so that whenever any user click on the old link of that post, they will be redirected to the new url.
Any help?

Comment: Can you provIde some examples of old and new links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} isaumya\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[0-9]+/?$ http://9tutorials.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache on the back end (highly likely), use mod_rewrite:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You dont understand. I dont want to copy the whole website to a new domain. What I'm saying is that suppose you have example.com within it you have example.com/blog/ Now you have purchased example2.com, in here you want to transfer all the blog posts from exaple.com. So now all you blog posts are indexed as example.com/blog/textpost but when people click it it will redirect them to example2.com/testpost

Comment: Sorry; I linked you to an outdated page. The corrected link is in the edited answer (above.)